# How to reset the default settings store path in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

With importing and exporting settings I've somehow changed the default save location for the settings in VS 2017 - they're landing on my Desktop. Also a settings reset did not help.

I want it do be the default path again. Any ideas are welcome. Btw. it's VS 2017 Enterprise with all latest updates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found it by myself.

The filename and path can be changed under "Options" -> "Environment" -> "Import and Export Settings". And the default path and filename is: c:\users\USERNAME\documents\visual studio 2017\settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'default save location', is it the location you're prompted to save when you create a solution first?

If so, go to Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General, and you can change those locations there.

Comment: No. I mean the save location of the settings file ""